# Auto-mount filesystems on boot fails (12.10)

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, encryption

I have a Compaq HP 8200 slim desktop running 12.10 with encrypted partitions (set up with the text-based installer). Everything's working fine, except...

When I boot the computer, my /boot and /boot/efi directories refuse to mount automatically. I'm dropped to the root console, where I must enter 'mountall -v', and everything then continues on just fine.

This was happening under 12.04. I've recently upgraded to 12.10, and the problem persists. Except now, in addition to /boot and /boot/efi not mounting, roughly 50% of the time /var will not be auto-mounted as well (and again, 'mountall -v' fixes allows me to boot and move on).

I'm puzzled about this one. Running 'fsck' doesn't seem to do anything (the filesystems aren't damaged anyway). What can I try to solve this issue?

Here's my /etc/fstab: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1338508/

Thanks in advance!!!

Addendum: I have tried changing the entries in fstab from UUIDs to the actual devices, to no avail.